# databricks cli dbfs command is is throwing error

Tags: databricks, databricks-cli

I am trying to execute below command in git bash as well as in cmd. However its not working. databricks cli is already installed using pip install databricks-cli installed

- dbfs rm -r dbfs:/reco/user/feature/branch
  Error: TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)

Comment: what version of databricks-cli, and python?

Comment: python -3.8, databricks cli- Version 0.11.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uninstalling pyspark 3 worked for me. I am still using python 3.8.5 so looks like issue was after installing pyspark 3

Answer (score 1):

It's a [known issue with Python 3.8](https://github.com/databricks/databricks-cli/issues/301), workaround is to use Python 3.7 or to uninstall pyspark 2.4.x that it's incompatible with Python 3.8 anyway...

Comment: uninstalling pyspark 3 worked for me. I am still using python 3.8.5 so looks like issue was after installing pyspark 3

Comment: Hmmm, I run with pyspark 3 and didn't have this problem - it was only with Spark 2.4. Can you add your comment to the Github issue that I linked?